# Evaluate $\lim_{x\to\infty}\left (\frac{1}{x}+2^{\frac{1}{x}}\right)^x$

Tags: calculus, limits, analysis, proof-writing

$$
\Large\lim_{x\to\infty}\left(\frac{1}{x}+2^{\frac{1}{x}}\right)^x\Large\\
=\Large\lim_{x\to\infty}\left(1+\left[\frac{1}{x}+2^{\frac{1}{x}}-1\right]\right)^x\Large\\
=\Large\lim_{x\to\infty}\left(1+\left[\frac{1}{x}+2^{\frac{1}{x}}-1\right]\right)^{\frac{1}{\frac{1}{x}+2^{\frac{1}{x}}-1}\color{red}{\left(1+x2^{\frac{1}{x}}-x\right)}}\Large\\
=\Large\lim_{x\to\infty} e^{\color{red}{\left(1+x2^{\frac{1}{x}}-x\right)}}
$$

I got trouble getting further (especially dealing with the type $0\cdot\infty$) and how to get around with it, please help, thank you for any comments.

Comment: If I am right, $\left(\frac1x+1+\frac{\log2}x+o(x^{-2})\right)^x\to e^{1+\log 2}$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have that
$$e^{1+x 2^{\frac{1}{x}}-x}=e^{1+x\left(2^{\frac{1}{x}}-1\right)}$$
Now recall that
$$\lim_{t \to 0} \frac{a^t-1}{t}=\lim_{t \to 0} \frac{e^{t \log a}-1}{t}=\lim_{t \to 0} \frac{e^{t \log a}-1}{t \log a} \cdot \log a$$
By putting $u=t \log a$ and noticing that $t \log a \to 0$ as $t \to 0$, hence
$$\lim_{t \to 0} \frac{e^{t \log a}-1}{t \log a} \cdot \log a=\lim_{u \to 0} \frac{e^u-1}{u} \log a =1 \cdot \log a =\log a$$

So, in $e^{1+x\left(2^{\frac{1}{x}}-1\right)}$, putting $z=\frac{1}{x}$ you have that $z \to 0$ as $x \to \infty$ and so
$$\lim_{x \to \infty} e^{1+x\left(2^{\frac{1}{x}}-1\right)}=\lim_{z \to 0^+} e^{1+\frac{2^z-1}{z}}=e^{1+\log 2}=e \cdot e^{\log 2}=2e$$
Alternatively, notice that since when $x \to \infty$ it is $\frac{1}{x}+2^{1/x}>0$, it is
$$\left(\frac{1}{x}+2^{1/x}\right)^x=\exp\left[x \log \left(\frac{1}{x}+2^{1/x}\right)\right]=\exp \left \{x \left[\frac{1}{x}\log 2 + \log\left(1+\frac{1}{x\cdot2^{1/x}}\right)\right]\right\}$$
Now use that $\log(1+t)=t+\text{o}(t)$ as $t \to 0$; I'm using $\exp \left[f(x)\right]=e^{f(x)}$ for better formatting.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I am not clear with $log(1+t)=t+o(t)$, what is $o(t)$? Would you please explain the second main equality a bit, I don't get the algebraic arrangement.

Comment: These are called Landau symbols: intuitively, $\text{o}(t)$ means "something that tends to $0$ faster than $t$". Hence, when you divide it by $t$, it tends to $0$. However, if you don't understand my answer because you still haven't studied Landay symbols, I will edit it trying to do something similar to your work. Wait a little, please.

Comment: @LJNG: I edited my answer. If this all clear now, you can upvote it and accept it.

Comment: genuinely thank you for your edited. This question comes from a Chinese web, provided with the answer $exp(1+ln2)$, I am not sure if your solution is correct.

Comment: Indeed, $\exp\cdot\,$ is clearer than $\mathrm e^\cdot$ here. Why not use it throughout?

Comment: @JohnBentin it was not a habbit

Comment: @LJNG: Did you read the solution properly? At some point I write $e^{1+ \log 2}$. It is equal to $2e$ for basic properties of exponentials and logarithms. If you still don't believe me, look at this https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=exp%281%2Bln%282%29%29%3D2e

Answer (score 4):

Taking the logarithm of the function and setting $t:=\dfrac1x$, we can use L'Hospital:

$$\lim_{t\to0}\frac{\log(t+2^t)}{t}=\lim_{t\to0}\frac{(1+2^t\log2)}{t+2^t}.$$

> $=1+\log 2$, giving the final answer $2e$.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Your final answer was correct, but setting $t=\frac{1}{x}$ does not make a denominator $t$

Comment: @LJNG: ouch, my bad, there was a logarithm missing ! Thanks for pointing that.

Comment: Making the change $t=1/x$ you should replace $x\to \infty $ with $t \to 0^\color{red}{+}$

Comment: @jjagmath : The limit is the same for $t\to0^+$ and $t\to0^-$.

Comment: In this case it's the same, but in general one should use the limit from above.

Comment: @BobbyLaspy I could catch up all the process, but where does that *the final answer $2e$* comes from?

Comment: @LJNG From $\exp(1+\log 2)$. BobbyLaspy took logarithm at the beginning of the solution.

Comment: @jjagmath: you are right. The limit was kind enough to exist both ways.

Answer (score 0):

As $x\to\infty$ we have $1/x+2^{1/x}=$ $1/x+e^{(\ln 2)/x}=$ $1/x+1+(\ln 2)/x+O(1/x^2).$

So $\lim_{n\to\infty} (1/x+2^{1/x})^{\,x}=$ $\lim_{n\to\infty}(\,1+\frac {1+\ln 2}{x}+O(1/x^2)\,)^{\,x}=$
$=\lim_{n\to\infty}(1+\frac {1+\ln 2}{x})^x=$ $e^{1+\ln 2}=2e.$